# Feature and a web part - what happens when you remove the feature

Tags: web-part, feature

I put a web part on a page through a feature.

I deactivate the feature.

Then when I go to activate it again, i loop through the wpManager.WebParts to determine if it is already on the page

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = site.GetLimitedWebPartManager(url + page, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared)) {
      try {
         SPLimitedWebPartCollection existingParts = wpManager.WebParts;

         //I loop through checking to see if it is on the page) here
    ...
```

If I manually activate/deactivate it all works fine.  The problem occurs when I activate the feature from another feature.  Yes, I have one feature that acts as a wrapper which then activates other features in a particular order.  Well, when activating this wrapper and doing the loop above the existingParts.Count = 0

I cannot explain this behavior. Ideas?

Comment: Can you give us some more details about for instance your "wrapper" works (and looks like in code)?

Comment: What scope is this other Feature?

Comment: @dave check the properties, I don't think they are coming through as expected to the child feature, wrong scope is the most likely scenario as James Love suggested.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is older than three months, the poster of the question hasn't been seen for three months and it contains no answers or no upvoted answers.
(see http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/close-old-unanswered-question?noredirect=1#comment1552_1014)